# Get current div and add html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I created on page where there is editable content.

I want to give user chance to add data on that page.

like, if they click 'textbox' there is will textbox in certain div.

but now if they add div and then inside that div, they want to add anything than how its possible ?

How can get current div(where my mouse current position), so if i select particular div which is editable, than they can add textbox inside it in.

checkout [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitz_88/HFMtL/), there is something like `document.activeElement` but its not working.

so how to get current div and add element into that particular div only.

When my mouse is in particular div / form than i want to add textbox / h1 should be added in particular that div / form.

P.S.

I need to get Id of my current cursor position.
if my cursor is inside form1 than i should get form1 and append html inside that.

i cant use `$(this)` because, this will return me where i clicked, not where my cursor position is.

Comment: `$(this)` would be useful

Comment: All your form-elements will have same id, which should never happen. Ids should be unique.

Comment: @Esa its for temporary. i will change that.

Comment: when i create something editable. so i can write text inside that form. than after some text i want to add into that particular form only. so i can add html using jquery but i need exactly where to add. so mouse blink will be in form as its editable. but this.id will give me id where i am clicking.

Answer (score 0):

apply this it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addForm").on("click", function(){
        var current = $(this);//use $(this) at the place of document.activeElement
        var myCurrentId = this.id;// here can also use $(this).attr("id");
        $(".uiHTML").append("<form id='1' contenteditable='true'></form>");
    });

    $(".addH1").on("click", function(){
        var current = $(this);
        var myCurrentId = this.id;// here can also use $(this).attr("id");
        $(".uiHTML").append("<h1>Hello</h1>");
    });
});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HFMtL/2/)**

Comment: i cant use this, bcz i am trying to add html where my cursor position.
i want to get my cursor position, like if its in form1 than it should add h1 inside form. if its in form2 than it should h1 in form2.

Comment: try to check the event.target of your click-handler's event parameter